# How to tell if connected to a website

Tags: networking, cross-browser, platform-independent

Is there an OS and browser neutral way to tell if someone is connected to a given website? Netstat doesn't seem to work because it shows only connections up to the router.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is a stateless protocol. There is no such thing as being "connected" to a website. If you're asking about the underlying TCP connection(s), there's *still* no guarantee that the connection is kept open across HTTP requests.